# What does the "ExtractAarTransform" in Gradle task "preDebugBuild" really mean?

Tags: android, gradle

I collected the Gradle log from my daily build in Android, and I am wondering what is the meaning of

> Executing transform `IdentityTransform` -> `ExtractAarTransform` -> `AarTransform` on artifact `support-core-ui.aar` (`com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0`)

Just add the `support-core-ui:28.0.0` aar to the classpath ? 
That's all?  correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For aar dependencies, it usually includes `.jar` (the class files), `aidl`, `jni` libs and resources, when you integrate it to your project, gradle tasks will *extract* those classes and other folders for subsequent steps to process, this is what `ExtractAarTransform` does, see source code [ExtractAarTransform](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/studio-master-dev/build-system/gradle-core/src/main/java/com/android/build/gradle/internal/dependency/ExtractAarTransform.java).

For `AarTransform`, it returns the content of an *extracted* AAR folder, see [AarTransform](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/studio-master-dev/build-system/gradle-core/src/main/java/com/android/build/gradle/internal/dependency/AarTransform.java)

Answer (score 0):

**AAR** or **Android Archive** is a file that you can use as a dependency for an Android app module and are used as Android Library. Read more [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library) about them. It is basically an archive format like JAR but containing Android App modules as well as layout etc files.

[Here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/support-core-ui/28.0.0)'s more about the specific android library support-core-ui:28.0.0 aar.